# In mongoDB, how can I find the previous doc by _id?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to return the previous and next mongo doc by _id.  The first one below works for the next, but the latter doesn't return the previous.  It returns the very first doc. I tried using `$sort` but it didn't seem to do anything.

```
    posts.findOne({'_id': {'$gt': identity}}, function(err, post) {
        "use strict";
        if (err) return callback(err, null);        
        callback(err, post);

    });

    posts.findOne({'_id': {'$lt': identity} }, {'$sort':-1}}, function(err, post) {
        "use strict";
        if (err) return callback(err, null);        
        callback(err, post);

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the right syntax for the `sort` option.  It would be:

```
posts.findOne({_id: {$lt: identity}}, {sort: {_id: -1}}, function(err, post) {
```

Comment: how come it is not $sort ?

Comment: I was assuming you're using the native node driver where it's `sort` (see [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findone)).  `$sort` is only used with `aggregate` AFAIK.